# Apply Duplicate Conditional Formatting across several columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can you apply the built in duplicate conditional formatting across multiple columns without using vba?  In other words, the duplicate test needs to be on only one column, but I'd like to highlight the entire row.  I don't want to highlight duplicates from any other column.

See below for example (created manually).  The duplicate highlighting is based on Cost and not on Name or Order#.  That is what I'm looking to achieve.  Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Use a formula based on the first row and leave the row relative while the column is absolute; e.g. `=countif($D:$D, $D3)>1` (where the first 10.00 is in D3 and the *Applies to:* is A3:D7).

Comment: I think that's totally gonna work!  Thanks!!!